# Adding duplicated rows to a dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

This may have been already solved somewhere else, but I can't find any specific link, so I'll be happy to see a "duplicated" tag...

I have a dataframe with rows that go like the following one:

```
  x y z lon lat count
1 A B C   0   0     3
2 B D Q   1   2     2
```

Now, to plot data with `ggmap` (I'm new and still learning about the grammar of graphics), specifically using the `stat_bin2d` I think that I should have to transform my above data in the following way:

```
  x y z lon lat 
1 A B C   0   0
2 A B C   0   0
3 A B C   0   0
4 B D Q   1   2
5 B D Q   1   2
```

Questions:

1) Is my assumption correct?

2) How can I reach my goal?

I've tried several ways to use `rbind` without a `for` loop, but I didn't solve my problem... The only way that I can think in my little knowledge of R language is something on the line of

```
my_df <- structure(list(x = structure(1:2, .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
                        y = structure(1:2, .Label = c("B", "D"), class = "factor"), 
                        z = structure(1:2, .Label = c("C", "Q"), class = "factor"), 
                        lon = c(0, 1), lat = c(0, 2), count = c(3, 2)), 
                   .Names = c("x", "y", "z", "lon", "lat", "count"), 
row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

for (i in 1:nrow(my_df)){
    for (j in 1:(my_df$count[i]-1)){
        my_df <- rbind(my_df, my_df[i,])}}
row.names(my_df) <- 1:nrow(my_df)
my_df <- my_df[,1:5]
```

Result is:

```
  x y z lon lat
1 A B C   0   0
2 B D Q   1   2
3 A B C   0   0
4 A B C   0   0
5 B D Q   1   2
```

It works, but I'd like to learn a better way to reach my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of a convenient function `expandRows` from `splitstackshape` to replicate the rows by the 'count' columns.

```
library(splitstackshape)
res <- expandRows(my_df, 'count')
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#  x y z lon lat
#1 A B C   0   0
#2 A B C   0   0
#3 A B C   0   0
#4 B D Q   1   2
#5 B D Q   1   2
```

Comment: thanks, it seems anyway that what the function `expandRows` does is actually the same of the above simplified solution, in a more elaborate and "professional" way: see https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape/blob/master/R/expandRows.R

Comment: @MaZe It has some additional functionalities as well as some check conditionalities to take care of cases where `count=0`.  And it has argument to either return the count column or not.  As I mentioned, it is a convenient wrapper.

Comment: yes, it's indeed a nice function. I think I will go for this solution, adding the function to my code without installing the whole package (for now, at least)... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do :

```
my_df[rep(seq_len(nrow(my_df)), times = my_df$count), ]
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481496/is-there-a-general-inverse-of-the-table-function)

Comment: I like the beauty and simplicity of this solution, but I don't really get all of how it works. It "subsets" `my_df` (actually, expanding it) including all columns (and this can be improved to drop the last one with the values), but how does it know how many times to repeat each row of `my_df` with just a single call to `my_df$count`?

Comment: I got it now. the single call throws out a vector of values, that's how it replicates the rows for the exact number of times. thanks, this is beautiful.