# R converting from short form to long form with counts in the short form

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, reshape2

I have a large table (~100M row and 28 columns) in the below format:

```
ID  A   B   C
1   2   0   1
2   0   1   0
3   0   1   2
4   1   0   0
```

Columns besides ID (which is unique) gives the counts for each type (i.e. A,B,C). I would like to convert this to the below long form.

```
ID  Type
 1   A
 1   A
 1   C
 2   B
 3   B
 3   C
 3   C
 4   A
```

I also would like to use data table (rather than data frame) given the size of my data set. I checked `reshape2` package in `R` regarding converting between long and short form however I am not clear if `melt` function would allow me to have counts in the short form as above.

Any suggestions on how I can convert this in a fast and efficient way in `R` using `reshape2` and/or `data.table`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822922/creating-a-table-with-individual-trials-from-a-frequency-table-in-r-inverse-of

Comment: Have you checked the [reshaping data.tables vignette](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)?

Comment: @Arun the vignette doesn't seem to have an example for the case where there are frequencies in the table instead..

Comment: @KTY, did you try the solution I shared in my answer?

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks for your reply. I used the `melt` as you suggested since it is faster with data tables. For the second step, instead of using `expandRows`, I separated the rows with more than one count and then `replicated` the ID and Type by count for only those rows, and then `merged` it with the original table. Seemed to work fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

You can try the following:

```
DT[, rep(names(.SD), .SD), by = ID]
#    ID V1
# 1:  1  A
# 2:  1  A
# 3:  1  C
# 4:  2  B
# 5:  3  B
# 6:  3  C
# 7:  3  C
# 8:  4  A
```

Keeps the order you want too...

---

You can try the following. I've never used `expandRows` on what would become ~ 300 million rows, but it's basically `rep`, so it shouldn't be slow.

This uses `melt` + `expandRows` from my "splitstackshape" package. It works with `data.frame`s or `data.table`s, so you might as well use `data.table` for the faster melting....

```
library(reshape2)
library(splitstackshape)
expandRows(melt(mydf, id.vars = "ID"), "value")
# The following rows have been dropped from the input: 
# 
# 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12
# 
#      ID variable
# 1     1        A
# 1.1   1        A
# 4     4        A
# 6     2        B
# 7     3        B
# 9     1        C
# 11    3        C
# 11.1  3        C
```